# Sublime Text 2 build system priority of selection in automatic mode

Tags: sublimetext2

How does Sublime Text 2 select which build system to use when 2 or more are created?  For example I have, installed in the order presented, Python 3 installed as well as wxPython 2.8 which uses Python 2.7.  I have added a new build system and found it resides in \Data\Packages\User.  These were the contents of that build system created:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\python27\\python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

The order they show up in tools->build system is: (from top to bottom)
Python
wxPython

I guess what I would like to accomplish is to have Python 3 as default, but allow myself to select 2.7 for projects that include wxPython.  Seems reasonable, but is it doable?

Answer (score 2):

For build systems with the same selector (in this case `source.python`), Sublime Text seems to override in the order they are imported (i.e. alphabetical).

A bit of a hack, but if your build files are named `wxPython.sublime-build` for 2.7 and `Python.sublime-build` for 3, then to give automatic build priority to 3 you could rename the former as `!wxPython.sublime-build` so that it is imported first and overriden.